# retrieve dialog value from NON modal dialog form

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I am working on an app and I'm trying to create a generic search form (form 2) that can be re-used the the entire application.

The search form will look through a DB and return an ID value of a selected item.

I can do this using the form (form 2) as a dialog and simply return the value to the calling form (form 1), but I want the form (form 2) to be non-modal and to remain open after the value is passed.

I know I can do this just calling `Form1.SubName(IDValue)` but I don't want to specify the form names manually (or with a case statement) as I may have as many as 10 forms calling this single search form.

I have tried setting the forms owner and doing `Me.Owner.SubName(IDValue)` but I get an error `'SubName' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'`.

Is there a way I can return the value from form 2 to form 2's owner and call a procedure on the calling form?

Comment: Cast it to the correct type (use TryCast). You could use an Interface, that every form that can start this searcher, implements.

Comment: What would I try casting to, the `Me.Owner` is already a form type?

Comment: Because a `System.Windows.Forms.Form` doesn't have your method, so you'll have to cast it to get the right type (that does have this method).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your requirement to both `return a value` and `call a procedure on the calling form`, I think the best solution would be to use `Events`. I'm going to go through a simple example to show the concept.

For this example, imagine you have a `Parent Form` and a `Child Form`, and each form has a `Button` and a `TextBox`.

1. Button click on the Parent Form will spawn a Child Form and subscribe to its ValueChanged event.
2. Button click on the Child Form will raise an event, and pass the value of its TextBox to anyone who has subscribed to the event.

Here is the code for the `Parent Form`:

```
Public Class ParentForm

    Private Sub ParentButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ParentButton.Click
        Dim child As New ChildForm
        AddHandler child.ValueChanged, AddressOf ChildFormValueChanged
        child.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChildFormValueChanged(ByVal NewValue As String)
        ParentTextBox.Text = NewValue
    End Sub

End Class
```

Here is the code for the `Child Form`:

```
Public Class ChildForm

    Public Event ValueChanged(ByVal NewValue As String)

    Private Sub ChildButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ChildButton.Click
        RaiseEvent ValueChanged(ChildTextBox.Text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The `AddHandler` code is important - it will allow the `Parent Form to subscribe to the Child Form's ValueChanged Event`, and also `specify a procedure to execute when the event has fired`. In this scenario, you will see that the Parent TextBox value will equal that of the Child TextBox whenever the ValueChanged event gets fired (in this example, this happens when the Child's Button is clicked).

You can put multiple arguments inside your Event declaration, and any data types, but you just need to make sure that the procedure that executes when it is raised (i.e. ChildFormValueChanged) has the same signature as the Event (expecting the same arguments and data types).

Answer (score 1):

I tried it this is how i made it work:
First you make an interface that all asking forms implement (thx for that lead Styxxy):

```
public interface IAsk
{
    void answer(String IDValue);
}
```

Now every time you call the search window you send the parent allong and just call the `parent.answer(IDValue)` methode wenn you have the answer.

```
public Form2(IAsk caller)
{
    parent = caller;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Hope this helps

Sry, for the bad english